# What is the Difference between these two Observable syntax

Tags: angular, rxjs

I am fairly new to Angular and am trying to figure what is the difference between these two syntax's of defining observables in angular and why I am getting an error in the second approach.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KQf6V.png)

```
  const customObservable = Observable.create((observer)=>{
  observer.next(this.data);
  })

  customObservable():Observable<Number>{
  return this.data;
  }
```

Comment: What is `this.data`?

Answer (score 0):

First one is variable of type Observable.

```
 // this.data is a value like: boolean/number/string

const customObservable = Observable.create((observer)=>{
  observer.next(this.data);
});
```

Second one is a function that return an Observable.

```
// this.data is an observable in this case.

customObservable():Observable<Number>{
  return this.data;
}
```